# Taking InnoDB MySQL/MariaDB cold file backup and restoring on new Omeka DB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb

I have an unresponsive Omeka MySQL/MariaDB database on a Windows server. It is unresponsive in the sense that it will not start from the XAMPP panel:

> 10:44:15 AM  [mysql]     Attempting to start MySQL app...  10:44:15 AM
> [mysql]     Status change detected: running  10:44:19 AM  [mysql]
> Status change detected: stopped  10:44:19 AM  [mysql]     Error: MySQL
> shutdown unexpectedly.  10:44:19 AM  [mysql]     This may be due to a
> blocked port, missing dependencies,  10:44:19 AM  [mysql]     improper
> privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.  10:44:19 AM
> [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
> 10:44:19 AM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
> 10:44:19 AM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
> 10:44:19 AM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums

The MySQL error log doesn't seem to be very helpful:

> InnoDB: using atomic writes. 2020-09-14 10:44:17 0 [Note] InnoDB:
> Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions 2020-09-14
> 10:44:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes 2020-09-14 10:44:17 0
> [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11 2020-09-14 10:44:17 0
> [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1 2020-09-14 10:44:17 0 [Note] InnoDB:
> Using SSE2 crc32 instructions 2020-09-14 10:44:17 0 [Note] InnoDB:
> Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size
> = 16M 2020-09-14 10:44:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool 2020-09-14 10:44:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128
> rollback segments are active. 2020-09-14 10:44:18 0 [Note] InnoDB:
> Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables 2020-09-14 10:44:18 0
> [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12
> MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ... 2020-09-14
> 10:44:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is
> now 12 MB. 2020-09-14 10:44:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to
> start 2020-09-14 10:44:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log
> sequence number 47055; transaction id 9 2020-09-14 10:44:18 0 [Note]
> InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
> 2020-09-14 10:44:18 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled. 2020-09-14
> 10:44:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200914
> 10:44:18 2020-09-14 10:44:18 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP:
> '::'.

The event logs indicates a corruption, however:

> Error      9/14/2020 10:44:18 AM MariaDB               100
> None     "Aborting" Error      9/14/2020 10:44:18 AM MariaDB
> 100         None     "Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege
> tables: Table '.\mysql\db' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?)
> repair failed" Error      9/14/2020 10:44:18 AM MariaDB
> 100         None     "mysqld.exe: Table '.\mysql\db' is marked as
> crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed"

I tried innodb_force_recovery set to 1, 2 and 3 but none worked. As I understand it, if I go any higher, it would result in data loss. So at this point, I think my options are pretty limited. I can't use any of the backup tools to take a data dump since they need the ability to log into the database. I can follow the steps here to physically make a cold backup of the database:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-backup.html

I can then try to recreate the blank database via Omeka/XAMPP and then restore the file. I was looking for feedback whether this seems like a reasonable plan or if there is an alternative in case others had faced a similar issue.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming therefore it is off topic here on SO. The dba sister site of SO offers help in troubleshooting database operations.

Comment: You'd follow a mysql 5.6 manual to repair a MariaDB?

Comment: My understanding was that MariaDB was a binary fork of MySQL. What would the MariaDB-specific approach to solving the issue be?